# MVC Bootstrap Datetimepicker showing wrong value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the datetimepicker found here, version 4.15.35: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

In my MVC application, when I'm on the create page, this works fine. The correct date is passed to the binder, and all is well! However, on the Edit page, the value is passed into the text box correctly, but once the script loads and turns the box into a datetimepicker, the date changes to today at midnight, even if I specifically load the date.

Script that runs:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    toolbarPlacement: 'top',
    showTodayButton: true,
    showClose: true,
    sideBySide: true,
    stepping: 15
});
```

Actual control:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Event.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker" } })
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post your `Edit` action in the controller?

Comment: It's a simple action that pulls the item from the context, and passes it to the View. If I disable javascript, the correct date shows, so it's not the controller. it's something with the javascript.

Comment: so you customized a `datetimepicker` that you found on your link and put it into your own .js file?

Comment: @bville_kid no, this was a package found through nuget

Comment: I am using the same thing in one of my applications... I am saying it looks like you customized the ability of one of the `datetimepicker` options because the options you are using don't happen on any of the examples on the link you gave

Comment: The only customizations I have are shown in the example. I did not modify the JS or CSS files at all, so I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: have you tried just using the basic `datetimepicker`?  `<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>`? In your case it would be ('.datetimepicker1') since yours is a class name and not an id